# Difference between "topic messages", "target messages", and "user segments" in Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I want to send push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging to users of my App. I have two categories:

1. Country 1
2. Country 2

In the settings of the app, users have radio buttons to subscribe to either Country 1 or Country 2. I already completed the steps described at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client and when I use `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`, I am obtaining the device token successfully. I was able to send notifications to single devices by using the compose message section of the Firebase console. The Firebase console has three radio buttons:

1) User segment
2) Topic
3) Single device

I understand how to send messages to single devices by using the device token. Now I am trying to fully understand the difference between "topic messages", "target messages", and "user segments". I was reading at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging the following information:

> Topic messages are optimized for throughput rather than latency. For fast, secure delivery to single devices or small groups of devices, target messages to registration tokens, not topics.

For what I need, I think using "topic messages" would be convenient, where I would have two topics: "Country 1" and "Country 2", and users decide to subscribe to the country they want to receive promotions from in this case.

"User segments" means that I take a group of device tokens and add them to a segment, and then I broadcast a push notification to that segment, correct? In the case of "topic messages", I would let users to subscribe to the country they want, and in my code I would have something such as the following lines to let someone subscribe to a specific country, correct?:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("country1");
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("country2");
```

Similarly, I would simply use `unsubscribeFromTopic("country1")` and `unsubscribeFromTopic("country2")` for unsubscribing users from topics.

I would appreciate if you could help by letting me know if my statements are correct or if you see that I am misunderstanding the conceptual differences between "topic messages", "target messages", and "user segments". Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conceptual answer that I was looking for is at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple

> Send Messages to Multiple Devices: Firebase Cloud Messaging provides two ways to target a message to multiple devices:
>   Topic messaging, which allows you to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic.
>   Device group messaging, which allows you to send a message to multiple devices that belong to a group you define.

Comment: [Device Group Messaging on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group) "Typically, "group" refers a set of different devices that belong to a single user." ?

Answer (score 0):

read this for your app's security....

Topic messaging allows any app client to subscribe to the ***topic***. Not so good for security as anyone can subscribe to. more reference [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)

Device groups are good as you define the security features of the group if anyone can access them or only a specified number of people can access the feature. more reference [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple)